# what is the default program to interpret windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am working on windows 7 and I found that "notepad" was set as the default program for opening my .bat files. So when I try to execute the batch file by double clicking, it is opened by notepad.

I have tried setting cmd.exe as the default program, which didn't work.

What is the default program I should set for executing .bat files?

Comment: just opens command prompt and does not execute the commands.

Answer (score 12):

Click on "Start"->"Run" and type in "REGEDT32" and press Enter to start the Registry Editor.

Find the following key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.BAT\UserChoice

and delete the key named "UserChoice".

Comment: typo (too small for me to correct, but you can): FileExts.BAT should be FileExts\.BAT

Answer (score 8):

Check the output of the following commands:

```
C:\>
C:\>assoc .bat
.bat=batfile

C:\>ftype batfile
batfile="%1" %*

C:\>
```

If your output is different, you have to correct the settings
(see `assoc /?` and `ftype /?` for help)

Comment: output is the same, I am still facing the issue.

Comment: Fantastic answer, probably the only one out there that doesn't talk about mucking around in the registry. Thank you @Stephan.

Answer (score 0):

Right click a bat file and select open with - and navigate to system32\cmd.exe

If it fails to apply the setting then security software may be blocking the registry changes.